# Always mark as "Looks safe"?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is it possible to mark emails that match a specific criterion as always "Looks safe" instead of having to click on "Looks safe" each time?

I don't think I found anything matching in the filter settings.

[image: Amber popup with "Report spam" and "Looks safe" buttons, and the following text:]

> **Be careful with this message**
> This may be a spoofed message. The message claims to have been sent from your account, but Gmail couldn't verify the actual source. Avoid clicking links or replying with sensitive information, unless you are sure that you actually sent this message. (No need to reset your password, the real sender does not actually have access to your account!)

Answer (score 0):

A gmail filter can be used to tell an incoming message to "Never send it to spam"

I use this for some emails that gmail might be tempted to flag as spam. I occasionally see a note attached to an email that it would have been flagged as spam except for the filter that said to not send to spam.